# Is the 8mm x 20mm bearing axle for the X-axis idler (of a P3Steel) a custom part?

Tags: printer-building, p3steel

Here is the X-axis of the P3Steel:

[image: X-axis arm of P3Steel]

The X-axis idler end of a P3Steel printer, employs an 8 mm diameter rod for the axle on which a 608zz bearing is mounted for the GT2 belt. This 8 mm rod is approximately 20 - 24 mm in length, with grooves at either end, for circlips.

A photo of the assembled idler, with the rod and circlips highlighted:

[image: X-axis idler end]

My question is: Does this part need to be custom made?

The short rod didn't come with the frame kit that I purchased (nor was it listed in the parts list, or shown in the photo of the parts - so it not as if it was omitted with my order). I have searched on eBay for it, using various search terms, and I am unable to find one. As I was not trained in mechanical engineering, I am not sure if this part has a special name, or is it just called a "smooth rod, with grooved ends"? I have also done a fair amount of googling, and although I have found some people who have constructed this particular frame, no one makes mention of this axle, nor any difficulties in sourcing it.

I have contacted the supplier of the frame, [Frame Prusa I3 P3Steel v4.0 +RODS](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Frame-Prusa-I3-P3Steel-v4-0-RODS-/182361720200?), and I am awaiting a reply.

This missing part is holding up my build progress - I already have the 608zz bearing and circlips.

---

#### Additional images

This image shows the "exploded view" and the 8mm rod can be clearly seen:

[image: Exploded view of the parts of X-axis idler]

Here are images of the assembled idler, showing the bearing inside -

Front view:

[image: Front view]

Side view:

[image: Side view]

This images are a little blurry, as they are screen shots taken from the video, [I3 Steel CORDOBESA con extrusor/with extruder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iDtDiW0kTSc).

Comment: It almost looks like a rivit..

Comment: @StarWind - I can see what you mean, but it's not a rivet, there are circlips on the front and (I assume) the rear also. I'll try to find a better photo - that picture was a screenshot from a YouTube assembly video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look up a [Clevis pin](https://www.pivotpins.com/products/bc-clevis-pins-with-grooves.html) with one groove.
You could look up a [Clevis pin](http://technifast.co.uk/clevis-pins) with a hole for a split pin.
Perhaps a [Shoulder screw](https://www.ondrives.com/303-stainless-steel-shoulder-screws#/pageSize=25&orderBy=5&pageNumber=3) with a ground shank and a low profile head.
Use a plain rod with [Dome caps](http://www.bakfin.com/starlock/metric-capped-roundshaft.html) if you will not need to remove often.
If available an internal threaded [Standoff](https://www.unicorpinc.com/metric-standoffs.htm) would work.
A [Slotted spring pin](https://www.ondrives.com/carbon-steel-slotted-spring-pins) may work if the hole dimensions are suitable.

**EDIT:**
You could also cut the grooves yourself pretty easily.  Cut a section of 8mm rod to length and mount it into a drill chuck so it stick out 2-3mm 1/8". Hold a hacksaw at the edge of the chuck and run the drill for a minute with gentle pressure, try hacksaw on other side or reverse direction if nothing is happening.
A hardened rod will cut better with a Dremel type cut-off disk

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Oh fascinating. It took me a while to figure out what exactly that is. It is a smooth rod used as the idler for the X belt.

What I would do is get a bearing / wheel. Take a thicker screw, nut and washer. Put the idler / bearing / wheel into the slot, then fit the screw / nut. Should work without any issue!

That said they likely had some sort of special fitting etc. Doesn't matter so long as the belt can move without wearing.

[This Thingiverse](http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:157303) does exactly what I am thinking.

[image: bolt example]

As you have a low profile need due to the interesting design I came across [this](https://www.belmetric.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=4030&cPath=3_569_718&gclid=CM6Pifm5rtECFVK5wAodMq8HLg&zenid=9o5khnodisqvndhvoejl6b6t40). a TNF8 - Nut Sert - Flanged/Ribbed.
[image]

Or you may just need a standard low profile nut. Not like you need it to do more than hold it in..
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The smooth rod is not the idler, per se, yet it _is_ the axle for a 608zz bearing. I have updated my question, with additional images and a link to an assembly video, that I found on YouTube. I had considered using an M8 Bolt, however, space is rather tight, and the head of the bolt could interfere with both the Z-axis 5 mm smooth rod and the M5 threaded rod (or M8 lead screw). Hence the requirement for the grooved rod, and the circlips, as this requires less clearance.

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I thought it was 

Comment: Yeah that is a tight design. Contacting the MFG for the part / the seller is best.. Else you will be Epoxying that thing together...

Comment: You know they do sell thin nuts. Edited answer for something that may help

Comment: -The nut sert looks promising. :)

Comment: I do hanker after that special short rod though. I have contacted my Polish supplier, but as I mentioned, they aren't very communicative. I may need to try to contact the Spanish chaps who designed the idler, if/when I manage to locate them.

Answer (score 1):

I have finally received a reply from my supplier, which backs up StarWind's answer:

> I did not use a rod with grooves for retaining rings.
>
> I used bolts and nuts with a thin head.

Doesn't really answer my question though, as I really rather hanker after the 8 mm smooth rod with the circlip grooves.